# How to add tuples in list in python

Tags: python, list, sum, tuples

I have the follwing list of tuples:

```
[[(16,)], [(2,)], [(4,)]]
```

I want to sum up the numbers inside, but fail to to so.

I tried

```
res = sum(*zip(*resultsingle))

res = sum(map(sum, resultsingle))
```

but i get the error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: That's not a list of tuples, it's a list of lists of tuples.

Comment: You open to using `numpy`? cause `numpy.sum([[(16,)], [(2,)], [(4,)]])` will do it.

Comment: Will the tuples always have exactly one element? Will the lists containing those tuples?

Comment: Can you write code that gets you the correct sum for just `[(16,)]`? What if you try wrapping that in a function, and using that with your existing `sum(map(` trick? (Also: do you know what a *list comprehension* is? How about a *generator expression*? Have you seen how to use these tools in conjunction with `sum`?)

Comment: @chris12 I tried numpy, but numpy.sum did not work, but maybe I messed it up.

Comment: @Karl - yes, I know about list comprehension and generators -  I am learning via a python bootcamp course, but I totally missed the list in list part, so it was destined to fail :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list is a nested list. Where you have a `list` containing `list`s, containing `tuple`.

This is a knows structure. And you can easily get each element and sum them. But let's say you have a nested list where you don't know how many lists or tuples are there or how they are nested?

In this case you'll need to flatten the list. Meaning, you get all the elements which are not `list` or `tuple`s and extend them into one list. For that you can use recursion:

```
def flatten(lst):
    dt = []
    if isinstance(lst, (list, tuple)):
        for each in lst:
            dt.extend(flatten(each))
    else:
        dt.extend([lst])
    return dt


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(flatten([1, [1, 2], 3, [1, [1, 2]]]))
```

Result:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2]
```

Now you only need to sum it:

```
print(sum(flatten([1, [1, 2], 3, [1, [1, 2]]])))
```

Result:

```
11
```

Comment: Oh gosh, I missed the nested List-in List part. I am selftaught so I slip up on things like this regulary. Thanks for the xplanation, I`ll wirte this down!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a nested comprehension would work:

```
>>> xss = [[(16,)], [(2,)], [(4,)]]
>>> sum(x for xs in xss for t in xs for x in t)
22
```

Comment: I tried this and it works! Thanks :)